# Remove specific strings from end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

From the end of a string I need to remove specific strings. I could do this with a loop, but I think it should be possible with a regex.

Example: remove all <br>, &nbsp; and whitespace from the end of my input string.

> "Hello world<br> <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; "

should become

> "Hello world".

I have tried various permutations of

```
$input = preg_replace('/(<br>| |&nbsp;)*$/', '', $input);
```

but in the end my regex knowledge fails me. How can I do this?

Comment: What is happening ? What are you getting ?

Comment: The code you've provided works when `$input = "Hello world<br> <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; ";`. Am I missing something? (PHP 5.4.19 (cli))

Comment: @Sniffer - one <br> remained.

Comment: @plasmid87 - I should have mentioned PHP 5.3, but I didn't think that made a difference. I'll try again with escaping.

Comment: It doesn't work, including escaping. What am I missing? Can it be the php version?

Comment: @Olaf: Can you post the *exact* code you're using to test this?

Comment: @AmalMurali - this is the exact code, just the input is different. The input is "User-ID<br><br>", and so is the output. But I have just found a \n newline, let me add that, that might be it.

Comment: O boy, embarrassing - I simply didn't see the newline characters in the debugger. Removing them did the job.

Thanks everybody for your time. In the end, the comment of @plasmid87 did the job because I took a closer look at the preconditions.

Comment: @Olaf: Try outputting it with `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. See my answer below.

Comment: @Jon: no, you don't need to escape these characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you've tried works just fine. Setting the `Content-Type` header to `plain` might help with debugging:

```
$string = "Hello world<br> <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; ";
$input = preg_replace('/(<br>| |&nbsp;)*$/', '', $string);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
var_dump($input);
```

Outputs:

```
string(11) "Hello world"
```

[3v4l demo.](http://3v4l.org/3GAvF)

Comment: As I wrote in the comments, that's exactly it, and you deserve the medal!

Comment: @Olaf: yay (!) - glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexes to parse HTML. With DOM it's:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('Hello world<br> <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;');
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo trim($selector->query('//text()')
    ->item(0)
    ->nodeValue
);
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

---

However if a regex solution is required - although knowing it better - use something like this:

```
preg_match('~(.*?)(&nbsp;|<br>)~', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: While in principle I agree with the first sentence, let's not get overzealous here. The goal is not to *parse* anything.

Comment: @Jon I think it is. I *would* use DOM here

Comment: What to use is open to discussion. What the stated goal is (cut off all specific suffixes from the input) is not. That's not parsing. You don't need to be able to parse JSON in order to remove a closing `}`.

Comment: @Jon removing the trailing `}` isn't related to extracting data. However, added a regex example. I hope it helps.. Still thinking the DOM solution is more stable.

Comment: Thanks, interesting suggestion. But if I query the text, won't this kill other html tags in that text? I definitely just want to get rid of these specific strings.

Comment: No is will remove everything after the first occurence of `<br>` or `&nbsp;` ... If the HTML gets more complex you might prefer DOM..

Comment: +1 for the suggestion - but the issue has been solved (and was based on my own blindness). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

If it is only HTML/PHP tags your are stripping you can use php `strip_tags` function [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$userInput ="Hello world<br> <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; ";

$input = rtrim(strip_tags($userInput));//to rtrim to remove any whitespace at the end
```

Comment: This won't strip the `&nbsp;`, and it will strip tags (assuming `strip_tags` doesn't mangle the string beyond recognition) *anywhere* in the input. This should be easy to see.